# How to upload default image from project folder when ng-src its empty?

Tags: json, angularjs

i have my ng-src `<img  ng-src="{{incident._links.thumbnail.href}}">`, the phat comes from a JSON object, how can i show a default image from my project folder like `<img  ng-src="img/default.jpg">` if the phat is empty

this is my JSON

```
"_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/incidents/5"
                },
                "attachments": {
                    "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/incidents/5/attachments"
                },
                "comments": {
                    "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/incidents/5/comments"
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/attachments/49/download"
                }
            }
```

and this is when its empty

```
"_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/incidents/5"
                },
                "attachments": {
                    "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/incidents/5/attachments"
                },
                "comments": {
                    "href": "http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/incidents/5/comments"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img  ng-src="{{incident._links.thumbnail.href || 'img/default.jpg'}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `ng-if` or `ng-show/ng-hide` .
Putting a condition like this

```
 <img ng-src="{{incident._links.thumbnail.href}}" 
ng-show="incident._links.thumbnail.href !== undifined && incident._links.thumbnail.href !== ''>

    <img ng-src="img/default.jpg" 
ng-show="incident._links.thumbnail.href === undifined || incident._links.thumbnail.href === ''>
```

Comment: it should be `undefined`, but why to check `undefined`?

Comment: You should accept answer if the answer solved your issue